# No hats in the user list in chat rooms

Tags: bug, chat, winter-bash-2016

I see hats in the main message window and near the input text field.

> [image: chat messages]

But no hats in the user list (right top corner) in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--):

> [image: user list]

Comment: I asked the same question 2 years ago :)

Comment: @DavidPostill why 2 if only 1 year?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment about 1 year.

Comment: @DavidPostill you question was asked 1 year ago (asked Dec 14 '15), not 2. Today is 2016 yet!

Comment: Ah. I misread the date (14 as year) ;)